# Time derivative if function evaluated on spacial boundary is zero

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem

I am working on the following problem:

[image]

If we know the dirichlet boundary condition that $u$ evaluates to zero on the spacial boundary, can we say anything about $u_t$ evaluated on the boundary? In particular do we have that
$$u_t |_{\delta U} = 0$$

Comment: Could you expand on this a little further? This doesn't make sense to me intuitively, since taking the derivative changes the function. When taking the partial derivative, although we treat the spacial variables as constants, we are still modifying the underlying function. Thanks in advance!